# How to get channel type using 'display clusqmgr(*)' command?

Tags: ibm-mq

Is there a way to get the channel type using the `display clusqmgr(*)` command? 
Following is the output of the command `display clusqmgr(*) all`
but this does not give the channel type.

```
AMQ8441: Display Cluster Queue Manager details.
   CLUSQMGR(QM_PR2_2)                      ALTDATE(2017-06-12)
   ALTTIME(15.00.07)                       BATCHHB(0)
   BATCHINT(0)                             BATCHLIM(5000) 
   BATCHSZ(50)                             CHANNEL(TO.QM_PR2_2)
   CLUSDATE(2017-06-20)                    CLUSTER(CLUSTER2)
   CLUSTIME(16.08.03)                      CLWLPRTY(0)
   CLWLRANK(0)                             CLWLWGHT(50)
   COMPHDR(NONE)                           COMPMSG(NONE)
   CONNAME(192.168.56.102(1434))           CONVERT(NO)
   DEFTYPE(CLUSSDRA)                       DESCR( )
   DISCINT(6000)                           HBINT(300)
   KAINT(AUTO)                             LOCLADDR( )
   LONGRTY(999999999)                      LONGTMR(1200)
   MAXMSGL(4194304)                        MCANAME( )
   MCATYPE(THREAD)                         MCAUSER( )
   MODENAME( )                             MRDATA( )
   MREXIT( )                               MRRTY(10)
   MRTMR(1000)                             MSGDATA( )
   MSGEXIT( )                              NETPRTY(0)
   NPMSPEED(FAST)                          PASSWORD( )
   PROPCTL(COMPAT)                         PUTAUT(DEF)
   QMID(QM_PR2_2_2017-06-12_15.00.06)      QMTYPE(NORMAL)
   RCVDATA( )                              RCVEXIT( )
   SCYDATA( )                              SCYEXIT( )
   SENDDATA( )                             SENDEXIT( )
   SEQWRAP(999999999)                      SHORTRTY(10)
   SHORTTMR(60)                            SSLCAUTH(REQUIRED)
   SSLCIPH( )                              SSLPEER( )
   STATUS(INACTIVE)                        SUSPEND(NO)
   TPNAME( )                               TRPTYPE(TCP)
   USEDLQ(YES)                             USERID( )
   VERSION(08000002)                       XMITQ(SYSTEM.CLUSTER.TRANSMIT.QUEUE)
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correction to my earlier answer, on further research the parameter that indicates the channel type in `DIS CLUSQMGR` output is `DEFTYPE` and is documented on the IBM MQ Knowledge center page "[DISPLAY CLUSQMGR](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q086110_.htm)".

The output of the `DIS CLUSQMGR` command is showing `CLUSQMGR` entries that the queue manager you ran it against knows about in any cluster or clusters it has joined.  If the queue manager it is ran on has successfully joined one or more clusters, this output will include the local queue manager (`CLUSRCVR`) as well as the full repositories (`CLUSSDRB`).  In addition if the local queue manager has also learned about any other partial repository queue managers (`CLUSSDRA`) these will show up as well.  If it has not successfully joined the cluster it may have only a `CLUSRCVR` and `CLUSSDR` listed, no `CLUSSDRA` or `CLUSSDRB` entries will be present.

> DEFTYPE How the cluster channel was defined:
>
> - CLUSSDR As a cluster-sender channel from an explicit definition.
> - CLUSSDRA As a cluster-sender channel by auto-definition alone.
> - CLUSSDRB As a cluster-sender channel by auto-definition and an
>     explicit definition.
> - CLUSRCVR As a cluster-receiver channel from an explicit definition.

The `CLUSRCVR` would be for the queue manager you ran this against's own Cluster Receiver channel.

The "by explicit definition" indicates it is a `CLUSSDR` defined on the queue manager you ran this against, you only need to define one `CLUSSDR` to one of the Full Repositories, the queue manager will learn the path to all full repositories after connecting to that full repository.  If it shows up as `CLUSSDR` in `DEFTYPE`, the queue manager has not yet successfully established a connection to the cluster full repository.  Once it connects to the full repository `DEFTYPE` will indicate it is both auto-definition and explicit (`CLUSSDRB`).

If it shows auto-definition only (`CLUSSDRA`) that is a queue manager the queue manager you run this on has learned about from the cluster.

Comment: this can't be true, see update to my question above.

Comment: Sorry, I take back my comment, I misread your comment, I thought you said it was cluster sender.

Comment: @Ajay if you agree with my answer you can roll back the last edit to your question and accept and up vote my answer.  I'll add a reference to the IBM Knowledge Center when I get some time later.